# Need to draw a shape for android in xml, the design will hold a "X" and some vertical and horizontal line also

Tags: android, xml

[Need to draw this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXtbV.png)
I need to draw this shape or design in xml, so how can i draw this

Comment: Use MS Paint. pretty simple. Because if you haven't tried even a bit by yourself or atleast research about your topic, MS Paint is the one to save your day. Cheers :)

Comment: Are you trying to draw the shape using vectors? If so, study [this](https://developer.android.com/training/material/drawables.html#VectorDrawables). as asked, you question is too broad. if you try making this graphic an run into specific problem, then ask it on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using a `<vector>` drawable for this.

```
<vector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0">

    <path
        android:strokeColor="#000"
        android:strokeWidth="1"
        android:pathData="M1 1h22v22h-22zM1 1l22 22M1 23l22 -22M1 12h22M12 1v22"/>

</vector>
```

[image]